# Google Play In-App Purchase Troubleshooting

Tags: unity, c#, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-purchase

I used the code below to handle in-app purchasing in my Unity 2019.1.9 game on Google Play.

But it did not work. What is my problem, and how can I fix it?
PLease answer me, why no people answer in this web site?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;


public class ShopManager2 : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener{

    public static ShopManager2 Instance{ set; get;}
    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;          
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider; 
        public static string PRODUCT_gold = "com.de.ss.gold";
        private void Awake(){
            Instance = this;
        }
    private void Start()
    {

    if (m_StoreController == null)
    {

    InitializePurchasing();
    }
    }

    public void InitializePurchasing() 
    {
    // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
    if (IsInitialized())
    {
    // ... we are done here.
    return;
    }

    // Create a builder, first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores.
            var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

    builder.AddProduct(PRODUCT_gold, ProductType.Consumable);

    UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }
    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
    // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
    return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }

    public void golds()
    {
        BuyProductID(PRODUCT_gold);
    }
            /*public void BuyNonConsumable()
            {
                // Buy the non-consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either 
                // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
                BuyProductID(kProductIDNonConsumable);
            }


            public void BuySubscription()
            {
                // Buy the subscription product using its the general identifier. Expect a response either 
                // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
                // Notice how we use the general product identifier in spite of this ID being mapped to
                // custom store-specific identifiers above.
                BuyProductID(kProductIDSubscription);
            }*/


    private void BuyProductID(string productId)
            {
                // If Purchasing has been initialized ...
                if (IsInitialized())
                {
                    // ... look up the Product reference with the general product identifier and the Purchasing 
                    // system's products collection.
                    Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

                    // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
                    if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                        // ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed 
                        // asynchronously.
                        m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
                    }
                    // Otherwise ...
                    else
                    {
                        // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                        Debug.Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
                    }
                }
                // Otherwise ...
                else
                {
                    // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or 
                    // retrying initiailization.
                    Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
                }
            }


        /*  // Restore purchases previously made by this customer. Some platforms automatically restore purchases, like Google. 
            // Apple currently requires explicit purchase restoration for IAP, conditionally displaying a password prompt.
            public void RestorePurchases()
            {
                // If Purchasing has not yet been set up ...
                if (!IsInitialized())
                {
                    // ... report the situation and stop restoring. Consider either waiting longer, or retrying initialization.
                    Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
                    return;
                }

                // If we are running on an Apple device ... 
                if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer || 
                    Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer)
                {
                    // ... begin restoring purchases
                    Debug.Log("RestorePurchases started ...");

                    // Fetch the Apple store-specific subsystem.
                    var apple = m_StoreExtensionProvider.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
                    // Begin the asynchronous process of restoring purchases. Expect a confirmation response in 
                    // the Action<bool> below, and ProcessPurchase if there are previously purchased products to restore.
                    apple.RestoreTransactions((result) => {
                        // The first phase of restoration. If no more responses are received on ProcessPurchase then 
                        // no purchases are available to be restored.
                        Debug.Log("RestorePurchases continuing: " + result + ". If no further messages, no purchases available to restore.");
                    });
                }
                // Otherwise ...
                else
                {
                    // We are not running on an Apple device. No work is necessary to restore purchases.
                    Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not supported on this platform. Current = " + Application.platform);
                }
            }*/



            public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
            {
                // Purchasing has succeeded initializing. Collect our Purchasing references.
                Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");

                // Overall Purchasing system, configured with products for this application.
                m_StoreController = controller;
                // Store specific subsystem, for accessing device-specific store features.
                m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
            }


            public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
            {
                // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
                Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
            }


            public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
            {
                // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.

        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id,PRODUCT_gold, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            shopping.buy30 =2002;


            //DataHelper.instance.SaveState.Gold +=100;
            // TODO: The non-consumable item has been successfully purchased, grant this item to the player.
        }
                // Or ... an unknown product has been purchased by this user. Fill in additional products here....
                else 
        { 
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
                }

                return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
            }


            public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
            {
                // A product purchase attempt did not succeed. Check failureReason for more detail. Consider sharing 
                // this reason with the user to guide their troubleshooting actions.
                Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want this code to do, and what happens instead? Do you get any particular error message or unwanted behaviour? What are the steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Hello DMGregory♦This is a in app purchase code for google play that when customers buy it so it run shopping code,  this code worked on my game previous version i google play (apk) but when I change to (aab) file like 64bit and 32bit  so This code does not work, why?  What is problem?How I fix it?

Comment: Why no one answers me?

Comment: Because you still haven't explained what you're trying to do or what's going wrong. "In-App Purchasing" is a whole category of tasks. What one task do you need help with first? What are the steps you're taking to perform that task? What are the results you observe when you do each step? Is there an error message or an unexpected outcome? These details will help us identify what kind of help you need, so edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: DMGregory♦ This is My Iap code that aatached to "Buy" button  for my game when paid  it run shopping.cs so now When I upload on googleplay "Buy" Button so After clicking customers
Nothing happens and no purchase..that is all,How can I write a code correctly , what is wrong in this code?

Comment: PLease answer me, why no people answer in this web site?

Comment: Look, No one can answer your question blindly. So i suggest create a development build to test device and connect it to log cat and then press buy button and check what sort of issue are you getting. If you post that issue from log cat. I hope some one can help you out. currently if some answer your question that will just a guess.